# Netty 4 code to run blocking operations in thread pool

Tags: netty

The documentation doesn't give any details on the different types of executors available.  What I want is to have an executor that's based on a configurable thread pool, much like the MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor that was in netty 3.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 6):

When you add a handler to a pipeline, you can specify an `EventExecutorGroup` along with the handler:

```
EventExecutorGroup executor = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(...);
...

ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
p.addLast(executor, new MyHandler());
```

`EventExecutorGroup` is similar to `OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor` except that it does not enforce any memory constraints.  You'll have to implement your own handler to enforce a memory constraint - `MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor` was not very efficient and often had performance problem.

There's no replacement for `MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor` because all handler methods in Netty 4 are invoked sequentially for the same connection.  If you want unordered execution, you'll have to hand off the tasks to a `java.util.concurrent.Executor`.  This decision is intentional - otherwise a handler implementation cannot make any consumption about thread safety.

Comment: DefaultEventExecutor is not public.  I can't find a single example of something that actually works with the lateast CR1.  I'm using DefaultEventExecutorGroup instead, which seems to work but leaves me wondering what I'm realy supposed to be doing here.

Comment: Also, Netty submits a OneTimeTask which has getValue() which returns AbstractChannelHandlerContext. There's no apparent way I found to grab the msg object called to your handler. The only place you have access to this object is the read method on your handler which is too late if you want to count the bytes coming *into* the queue and not out.